# go-grpc return TLS error `unrecognized name`

Tags: go, ssl, grpc, cfssl

I want to enable tls mode for go-grpc. But I get a connection error at the check tls step
`connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: remote error: tls: unrecognized name"`

I am trying to create a certificate via cfssl - [config](https://github.com/batazor/shortlink/tree/opentracing/ops/cert/conf)

My cert view:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            5d:31:fa:b4:45:04:46:8b:2c:48:1e:3d:23:29:1c:30:f4:9c:5b:b1
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = RU, ST = Moscow, L = Moscow, O = Shortlink, OU = Moscow, CN = localhost
        Subject: C = RU, ST = Moscow, L = Moscow, O = Shortlink, OU = Moscow, CN = localhost
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c9:da:...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                10:12:95:E3:6E:A6:E0:B9:85:02:AB:93:F4:F2:89:C5:4F:F9:F3:6E
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:localhost
```

Config go-grpc: [github](https://github.com/batazor/shortlink/blob/opentracing/internal/di/wire.go#L258-L319)

and all certs: [gist](https://gist.github.com/batazor/11a33f4095a6fe3b768055cf64003c8f)

Comment: This indicates that the server name (as passed into the `Dial` function) is not found in the certificate's Common Name or Subject Alternative Names. Without more details (such as your connection details and `openssl x509 -text -in <file.crt>` dump of the certificate), we can't help further.

Comment: @Marc I add view cert

Comment: Are you trying to connect to `localhost` using grpc? If not, this won't work.

Comment: yes, both services are running locally. Without TLS, they successfully exchanged commands

Comment: Please show more details such as your grpc connection setup (both client and server side), the tls configs, and all certificates/keys used (but don't show the contents of the keys).

Comment: @marc updated the description

Comment: Please read the [grpc/credentials](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials) package docs. You need to use `NewServerTLSFromFile` for the server side, passing both cert and key. For the client side, you either need to call `NewClientTLSFromFile` with the CA certificate, or you need to call `NewTLS` with a custom `tls.Config` object if you need client certificates (for client auth). And don't ignore errors from any of those functions, they are likely all failing right now.

Comment: This is environment dependent. For example in Linux Ubuntu & Debian most of the time you have to install the ca-certificates package to make the certs work.

Comment: @Marc thank you for your help. Only now I realized that I used the NewServerTLSFromFile method for both the client and the server.

Comment: I'm at the same issue, I read the documentation but I can't make a tls handshake. Is there a working example for simple tls communication?

Comment: @Totalys Take a look at https://github.com/batazor/shortlink/blob/main/pkg/rpc/server.go#L81-L88